# Update Magento Special Price

Tags: php, magento, e-commerce

I'm trying to revert "special price" after the "special price to date" passed to null. So basically when I update my product's special price programmatically using this code :

```
$todayDate  = Mage::app()->getLocale()->date()->toString(Varien_Date::DATETIME_INTERNAL_FORMAT);

$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
        ->addStoreFilter()
        ->addAttributeToFilter('special_price', array('gt' => 0))
        ->addAttributeToFilter('special_to_date', array('date' => true, 'to' => $todayDate));
echo "Total products found : ".count($collection);
foreach ($collection as $product)
{
        $product->setSpecialPrice(null)
        ->setSpecialFromDate(null)
        ->setSpecialToDate(null)
        ->save();
}

echo "<br/> Done!";
```

But after I update my special price to null the magento product wizard does not let me set a new special price for my product. When I save the form it does not give me any error nor affect any changes in special price and it's still null! What's wrong?!

Comment: Have you checked that logging is enabled and that there are no entries of interest in exception.log or system.log?  Can you post anything relevant from them?

Comment: The problem was so funny! I wrote this code in 3 different ways using API and direct db access and the result was the same, turned out there was something wrong with my Magento installation and the works like charm in other installations! Silly Magento!

Comment: Cant reproduce your bug on Magento 1.4.2.0. Everything works as planned.

Answer (score 6):

To solve this, pick what suits for you more.
you can either set the "ToDate" in the past like:

```
->setSpecialToDate(date("m-d-Y", strtotime('-25 year')));
```

just beware that if you want to set it back, you will have to set the "ToDate" in the future like:

```
->setSpecialToDate(date("m-d-Y", strtotime('25 year')));
```

or instead of 'null', just insert an empty string ''.
like so:

```
$product->setSpecialPrice('')
        ->setSpecialToDate('')
        ->setSpecialFromDate('')
        ->save()
```

hope this helps someone out